# N choose N/2 sublists of a list

Tags: python, list, permutation, combinatorics

Is there an efficient way in Python to get all partitions of a list of size `n` into two subsets of size `n/2`? I want to get some iterative construct such that each iteration provides two non-overlapping subsets of the original list, each subset having size `n/2`.

For example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    # here n = 6
# some iterative construct
    # in each iteration, a pair of subsets of size n/2
    # subsets = [[1,3,4], [2,5,6]] for example for one of the iterations
    # subsets = [[1,2,5],[3,4,6]] a different iteration example
```

The subsets should be non-overlapping, e.g. `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` is valid but `[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]]` is not.  The order of the two subsets does not matter, e.g. `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` does not count as different from `[[4,5,6], [1,2,3]]` and thus only one of those two should appear in an iteration. The order within each subset also does not matter, so `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`, `[[1,3,2], [4,5,6]]`, `[[3,2,1], [6,5,4]]`, etc. all count as the same and so only one of them should show up in whole iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: @idjaw oh, i think you're more right. Can i cancel my duplicate warning?

Comment: @idjaw I am actually very lowly of points, i can't vote on things. that was just a flag that i raised.

Comment: @idjaw: This isn't a duplicate of that question how to split into evenly sized chunks; chunking is separate from arbitrary subsets.

Comment: Do the two lists of size n/2 have to be non-overlapping?  Or is `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` a valid iteration?

Comment: Also, what if n is odd?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Non-overlapping. Also, I am guaranteed that the length of the list will be even.

Comment: Also, you're using the terminology "choose" and "combination".  I take that to mean order doesn't matter?  However you also say "sublist", which implies order matters.  Do you intend to treat `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` as the same as `[[3,2,1], [6,5,4]]`?  What about `[[4,5,6], [1,2,3]]`?

Comment: The ones that you listed should all count as one (they should be treated as the same).

Comment: Do you want the output to include both `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` **and** `[[4,5,6], [1,2,3]]`, or just one of those pairs?

Comment: @PM2Ring No, I do not. I also would not like to include for example `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` and `[[2,1,3],[4,5,6]]

Comment: FWIW, I've added a faster, simpler itertools solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `itertools`-based generator that I think yields exactly the values you want.

```
def sub_lists(sequence):
    all_but_first = set(sequence[1:])
    for item in itertools.combinations(sequence[1:], len(sequence)//2 - 1):
        yield [[sequence[0]] + list(item), list(all_but_first.difference(item))]
```

I avoid near-duplicate outputs in two ways as compared to a `permutations` based approach in Suever's answer. First, I avoid yielding both `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]` and `[["c", "d"], ["a", "b"]]` by forcing all the results to have the first value of the input sequence in the first sublist. I avoid yielding `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]` and `[["a", "b"], ["d", "c"]]` by building the second sublist using set-subtraction.

Note that yielding nested tuples might be a little more natural than nested lists. To do that, just change the last line to:

```
yield (sequence[0],) + item, tuple(all_but_first.difference(item))
```

Comment: Nice algorithm! I'm surprised that generating the combinations without the first element like this isn't significantly faster than my first combinations-based code that uses an `if` test to bail out of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to do this. The inputs are the list you want to select items out of and the second is the number of items to select.

```
result = [list(item) for item in itertools.combinations(input, len(input) // 2)]
```

For an input of `[1,2,3,4]` this yields

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

As [@ShadowRanger pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025609/n-choose-n-2-sublists-of-a-list/36025672?noredirect=1#comment59702154_36025672), if order matters in your lists and you want all permutations, you'll want to substitute `itertools.permutations` into the solution.

```
result = [list(item) for item in itertools.permutations(input, len(input) // 2)]
# [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

**Edit**

Upon reading your question closer it is unclear if you want all `n/2` permutations like I have shown or you want a list of lits where each element is yet *another* list of the two "halves" of the permutation.

To accomplish this, you could do the following (incorporating some indexing help [from @Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025609/n-choose-n-2-sublists-of-a-list/36025672?noredirect=1#comment59702368_36025672))

```
result = [[list(item[::2]), list(item[1::2])] for item in itertools.permutations(input)]
```

In this case, the output of `[1,2,3,4]` would be

```
[[[1, 3], [2, 4]], [[1, 4], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 4], [3, 2]], [[1, 2], [4, 3]], [[1, 3], [4, 2]], [[2, 3], [1, 4]], [[2, 4], [1, 3]], [[2, 1], [3, 4]], [[2, 4], [3, 1]], [[2, 1], [4, 3]], [[2, 3], [4, 1]], [[3, 2], [1, 4]], [[3, 4], [1, 2]], [[3, 1], [2, 4]], [[3, 4], [2, 1]], [[3, 1], [4, 2]], [[3, 2], [4, 1]], [[4, 2], [1, 3]], [[4, 3], [1, 2]], [[4, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[4, 1], [3, 2]], [[4, 2], [3, 1]]]
```

**Edit2**

Since order doesn't matter but you want an approach similar to the last one (lists of lists of lists), that's a little tricky with the last approach because of the array slicing. One alternative is to use `set` and [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) to construct the initial information (rather than lists), because in a `set` the ordering doesn't matter when checking for equality. This will automatically allow us to remove duplicates. We can then add an extra step to convert back to a list if that's what you prefer.

```
from itertools import permutations
tmp = set([frozenset([frozenset(k[::2]),frozenset(k[1::2])]) for k in permutations(input)]) 
result = [[list(el) for el in item] for item in tmp];
```

This will yield

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 3], [1, 4]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]
```

Comment: Possible they'd want `itertools.permutations` instead, unclear on whether order counts (they say "permutation", though the example has ordered selection, and the term "sublist" would often mean "combination", not "permutation"). Just mentioning it in case.

Comment: `[item[::2], item[1::2]]` would be another way of slicing the permutations in half, without needing to find the half-length first (not that that's a costly operation, of course).

Comment: @Suever The last post is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Blckknght would there also be a way of slicing combinations in a similar manner?

Comment: @user3501476: No, I don't think it would work right with the combinations as they're already being made in groups of `n//2`. Since they're ordered too, a slice wouldn't get an even sample. I'm pretty sure the `permutations` version is what you want anyway.

Comment: @Blckknght The problem is that I realized I don't want for example [  [[1, 2], [3, 4]],  [[1, 2], [4, 3]],  [[2,1], [4, 3]], [ [4,3], [2,1] ]... ]. So basically I don't care about order as well.

Comment: @user3501476 Answer has been updated with a solution that should yield what you want

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution which doesn't use itertools. It uses a trick called Gosper's hack to generate bit permutations. See [HAKMEM Item 175](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/hakmem-item-175/) for an explanation of how it works; this hack is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). And it features in the accepted answer to this SO question: [Iterating over all subsets of a given size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934122/4014959).

The `parts` function is a generator, so you can use it in a `for` loop, as illustrated in my test.

#### How it works.

To partiton a list of length *n* into pairs of sublists of length *n/2* we use a binary number `bits` consisting of *n/2* zero bits and *n/2* one bits. A zero bit in a given position indicates that the corresponding list element goes into the left sublist, a one bit in a given position indicates that the corresponding list element goes into the right sublist.

Initially, `bits` is set to `2 ** (n/2) - 1`, so if *n* = 6, `bits` starts out as `000111`.

The generator uses Gosper's hack to permute `bits` in numerical order, stopping when we get a one bit in the highest position, since that's when we start getting the reversed versions of our sublist pairs.

The code responsible for converting the pattern in `bit` into the pair of sublists is:

```
    for i, u in enumerate(lst):
        ss[bits & (1<<i) == 0].append(u)
```

If there's a zero at bit position `i` in `bits` then `ss[0]` gets the current item from `lst`, otherwise it's appended to `ss[1]`.

This code runs on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def parts(lst):
    ''' Generate all pairs of equal-sized partitions of a list of even length '''

    n = len(lst)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('list length MUST be even')

    lim = 1 << (n - 1)
    bits = (1 << n // 2) - 1

    while bits < lim:
        #Use bits to partition lst
        ss = [[], []]
        for i, u in enumerate(lst):
            ss[bits & (1<<i) == 0].append(u)
        yield ss

        #Calculate next bits permutation via Gosper's hack (HAKMEM #175)
        u = bits & (-bits)
        v = bits + u
        bits = v | (((v ^ bits) // u) >> 2)

# Test
lst = list(range(1, 7))
for i, t in enumerate(parts(lst), 1):
    print('{0:2d}: {1}'.format(i, t))
```

**output**

```
 1: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 2: [[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
 3: [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]]
 4: [[2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6]]
 5: [[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]]
 6: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
 7: [[2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
 8: [[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
 9: [[2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
10: [[3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 6]]
```

I admit that using something inscrutable like Gosper's hack isn't exactly Pythonic. :)

---

Here's how you capture the output of `parts` into a list of all the sublists. It also illustrates that `parts` can handle string input, although it produces the output as lists of strings.

```
seq = list(parts('abcd'))
print(seq)
```

**output**

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']], [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]]
```

---

Here's another solution, using itertools to generate the combinations. It generates the pairs in a different order to the earlier version. However, it's shorter and easier to read. More importantly, it's significantly faster, between 50 to 100 percent faster in my `timeit` tests, depending on the list length; the difference appears to get smaller for longer lists.

```
def parts(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('list length MUST be even')

    first = lst[0]
    for left in combinations(lst, n // 2):
        if left[0] != first:
            break
        right = [u for u in lst if u not in left]
        yield [list(left), right]

# Test
lst = list(range(1, 7))
for i, t in enumerate(parts(lst), 1):
    print('{0:2d}: {1}'.format(i, t))
```

**output**

```
 1: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 2: [[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
 3: [[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]]
 4: [[1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]]
 5: [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]]
 6: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
 7: [[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5]]
 8: [[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
 9: [[1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the orders matter, but we're making a list of lists of lists (where order inherently matters), we can assume some invariants: in all pairs, the first element in the first pair is 1, and both lists in a pair are in sorted order.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

from itertools import combinations
first, rest = A[0], A[1:]
result = [
            [
                list((first,) + X), 
                [x for x in rest if x not in X]
            ] 
            for X in combinations(rest, len(A)/2 - 1)
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that performs [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html?#module-timeit) tests on the various solutions to this problem.

To make the comparisons fair, I've commented out the argument-checking test in my functions.

I've also added a function `parts_combo_set` that combines features of my combinations-based answer with that of Blckknght. It appears to be the fastest, except for very small lists.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Generate all pairs of equal-sized partitions of a list of even length

    Testing the speed of the code at
    http://stackoverflow.com/q/36025609/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.03.16
'''

from __future__ import print_function, division
from itertools import combinations
from timeit import Timer

def parts_combo(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    #if n % 2 != 0:
        #raise ValueError('list length MUST be even')

    first = lst[0]
    for left in combinations(lst, n // 2):
        if left[0] != first:
            break
        right = [u for u in lst if u not in left]
        yield [list(left), right]

def parts_combo_set(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    #if n % 2 != 0:
        #raise ValueError('list length MUST be even')

    first = lst[0]
    allset = set(lst)
    for left in combinations(lst, n // 2):
        if left[0] != first:
            break
        yield [list(left), list(allset.difference(left))]

def parts_gosper(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    #if n % 2 != 0:
        #raise ValueError('list length MUST be even')

    lim = 1 << (n - 1)
    bits = (1 << n // 2) - 1

    while bits < lim:
        #Use bits to partition lst
        ss = [[], []]
        for i, u in enumerate(lst):
            ss[bits & (1<<i) == 0].append(u)
        yield ss

        #Calculate next bits permutation via Gosper's hack (HAKMEM #175)
        u = bits & (-bits)
        v = bits + u
        bits = v | (((v ^ bits) // u) >> 2)

def sub_lists(sequence):
    all_but_first = set(sequence[1:])
    for item in combinations(sequence[1:], len(sequence)//2 - 1):
        yield [[sequence[0]] + list(item), list(all_but_first.difference(item))]

def amit(seq):
    first, rest = seq[0], seq[1:]
    return [
                [
                    list((first,) + t), 
                    [x for x in rest if x not in t]
                ]
                for t in combinations(rest, len(seq) // 2 - 1)
           ]

funcs = (
    parts_combo,
    parts_combo_set,
    parts_gosper,
    sub_lists,
    amit,
)

def rset(seq):
    fset = frozenset
    return fset([fset([fset(u),fset(v)]) for u,v in seq])

def validate():
    func = funcs[0]
    master = rset(func(lst))
    print('\nValidating against', func.func_name)
    for func in funcs[1:]:
        print(func.func_name, rset(func(lst)) == master)

def time_test(loops, reps):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.func_name
        print('\n%s' % fname)
        setup = 'from __main__ import lst,' + fname
        #cmd = 'list(%s(lst))' % fname
        cmd = 'for t in %s(lst):pass' % fname
        t = Timer(cmd, setup)
        r = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        r.sort()
        print(r)


num = 6
lst = list(range(1, num + 1))
print('num =', num)

#parts = funcs[0]
#for i, t in enumerate(parts(lst), 1):
    #print('{0:2d}: {1}'.format(i, t))

validate()
time_test(10000, 3)
```

**outputs**

`time_test(10000, 3)`

```
num = 6

Validating against parts_combo
parts_combo_set True
parts_gosper True
sub_lists True
amit True

parts_combo
[0.58100390434265137, 0.58798313140869141, 0.59674692153930664]

parts_combo_set
[0.74442911148071289, 0.77211689949035645, 0.79338312149047852]

parts_gosper
[1.0791628360748291, 1.089813232421875, 1.1191768646240234]

sub_lists
[0.77199792861938477, 0.79007697105407715, 0.81944608688354492]

amit
[0.60080099105834961, 0.60345196723937988, 0.60417318344116211]
```

`time_test(1000, 3)`

```
num = 8

Validating against parts_combo
parts_combo_set True
parts_gosper True
sub_lists True
amit True

parts_combo
[0.22465801239013672, 0.22501206398010254, 0.23627114295959473]

parts_combo_set
[0.29469203948974609, 0.29857206344604492, 0.30069589614868164]

parts_gosper
[0.43568992614746094, 0.44395184516906738, 0.44651198387145996]

sub_lists
[0.31375885009765625, 0.32754802703857422, 0.37077498435974121]

amit
[0.22520613670349121, 0.22674393653869629, 0.24075913429260254]
```

`time_test(500, 3)`

```
num = 10

parts_combo
[0.52618098258972168, 0.52645611763000488, 0.53866386413574219]

parts_combo_set
[0.40614008903503418, 0.41370606422424316, 0.41525506973266602]

parts_gosper
[1.0068988800048828, 1.026188850402832, 1.1649439334869385]

sub_lists
[0.48507213592529297, 0.50991582870483398, 0.51528096199035645]

amit
[0.48686790466308594, 0.52898812294006348, 0.68387198448181152]
```

`time_test(100, 3)`

```
num = 12

parts_combo
[0.47471189498901367, 0.47522807121276855, 0.4798729419708252]

parts_combo_set
[0.3045799732208252, 0.30534601211547852, 0.35700607299804688]

parts_gosper
[0.83456206321716309, 0.83824801445007324, 0.87273812294006348]

sub_lists
[0.36697721481323242, 0.36919784545898438, 0.38349604606628418]

amit
[0.40012097358703613, 0.40033888816833496, 0.40788102149963379]
```

`time_test(50, 3)`

```
num = 14

parts_combo
[0.97016000747680664, 0.97931098937988281, 1.2653739452362061]

parts_combo_set
[0.81669902801513672, 0.88839983940124512, 0.91469597816467285]

parts_gosper
[1.772817850112915, 1.9343690872192383, 1.9586498737335205]

sub_lists
[0.78162002563476562, 0.79451298713684082, 0.8126368522644043]

amit
[0.89046502113342285, 0.89572596549987793, 0.91031289100646973]
```

`time_test(50, 3)`

```
num = 16

parts_combo
[4.1981601715087891, 4.3565289974212646, 4.3795731067657471]

parts_combo_set
[2.5452880859375, 2.5757780075073242, 2.6059379577636719]

parts_gosper
[7.5856668949127197, 7.6066100597381592, 7.6397140026092529]

sub_lists
[3.677016019821167, 3.6800520420074463, 3.7420001029968262]

amit
[4.1738030910491943, 4.1768841743469238, 4.1960680484771729]
```

`time_test(10, 3)`

```
num = 18

parts_combo
[3.8362669944763184, 3.8807728290557861, 4.0259079933166504]

parts_combo_set
[1.9355819225311279, 1.9540839195251465, 1.9573280811309814]

parts_gosper
[6.3178229331970215, 6.6125278472900391, 7.0462160110473633]

sub_lists
[2.1632919311523438, 2.238231897354126, 2.2747220993041992]

amit
[3.6137850284576416, 3.6162960529327393, 3.6475629806518555]
```

`time_test(10, 3)`

```
num = 20

parts_combo
[16.874133110046387, 17.585763931274414, 19.725590944290161]

parts_combo_set
[7.5462148189544678, 7.5597691535949707, 7.8375740051269531]

parts_gosper
[27.312526941299438, 27.637516021728516, 28.016690015792847]

sub_lists
[7.7865769863128662, 7.8874318599700928, 8.5498230457305908]

amit
[15.554526805877686, 15.626868009567261, 16.224159002304077]
```

These tests were performed on a 2GHz single-core machine with 2 GB of RAM running Python 2.6.6.